# How do I find the dependencies on a dll :: GLUT specifically

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, opengl, compiler-construction

I have been learning opengl for about 4-5 months now. 
I am ready to stop using glut(a helper library that obfuscates many difficult / tedious aspects of opengl programming )

**Problem is,** I feel I have removed all refrences to glut.h, as well as all function calls within glut, but when I run my application it is still trying to link to glut32.dll.

Generally so I and others can learn for later, 
How can I tell which libraries an excutable/source-code need and why(function/header wise), either before or after compile?

I am using VS2010 but cross compiling this on a linux box with g++
In this specific instance I don't have the dll listed as an additional dependency . But I do see glut.h in the extrenal dependencies folder...i just cant remove it

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) is your friend for examining the dll dependencies of compiled binaries.

The principal problem is of course, you have added glut.lib or glut32.lib to your project someplace. Its probably in the Project Properties > Linker Settings > Additional Libraries, or some source file contains a #pragma something like this :-

```
#pragma comment(lib, "glut32.lib")
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the linker properties for you project(s).  The dll, or rather, the corresponding .lib should be listed there under "additional dependencies".

Edit:

By the way, including a header and linking a library (or a dll) are two different things.  You may be including a header somewhere, but not linking to the corresponding library.  In that case, the linker will give you an error.  On the other hand, you may not be including the header, and not using the library at all, but you may still be linking to it.

In this case it seems like we have both.  If glut.h is in the external dependencies folder then you must be including it somewhere in your code.  Try using find-in-files to look for it.  Or delete it from your system altogether and try to compile.

Comment: as stated in the question, its not listed there. (properties > linker > input > Additional Dependencies) ;

but I do see %(AdditionalDependencies) in that list - which bothers me...where is this variable refrencing???

Comment: Sorry, but in the question you mentioned "external dependencies folder"...  In any case, the first thing to try would be to remove the AdditionalDependencies variable and see what happens.  The next thing to try is to look at properties->CommonProperties->Frameworks and References.  By the way is glut32 a project in your solution, by any chance?

Comment: Thanks you for your help and return answer. I was able to find where the .h was being refrenced...I am also in the process of removing the need for stdafx.h and in the confusion it was linking to an old version of another .h, which needed....glut.h - fail and thanks to you

Answer (score 1):

Every exe/dll has something called an Import Address Table (IAT) which is information stored in the PE (Portable Executable: window's executable file format) file's header about what dlls the loader needs to load when the module in question is loaded. You can use tools like PE Viewer or PE Explorer to view this information or write your own (this is more difficult). What you will see are libraries that are statically linked to your executable. If you don't see glut32.dll in any of those files, it is possible that it is loaded dynamically through LoadLibrary api in some other openGL library. I am not very familiar with openGL binaries, so I cannot confirm this for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems to find where glut.lib is hidden in the visual studio project options, open the .vcproj in a standard text editor and make a full text search.